# What's the difference between using std::cout and using ::std::cout?

Tags: c++, namespaces

As we already know `::` is global namespace. And we have already know [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236404/what-is-using-namespace-pollution) using namespace has some downsides.

So we decide to type less and type in the beggining of our file `using ::std::cout;`, but we can also type `using std::cout;`. So is there any difference?

Comment: Not in global scope.

Comment: `namespace dont { namespace trythis { namespace athome { namespace std { int cout;  } using std::cout; } } }`

Comment: If you don't use any inner namespaces called `std`, then it's just a matter of style, but I've only ever known one single person who actually wrote `::std::cout`. I'd say it's extremely uncommon.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As for myself, I wasn't 100% sure if there weren't any ADL issues worth to be mentioned, rendering the "it's just a matter of style" part incorrect, so I've limited my input to a comment.

Comment: @Christian: I would suggest that if you're not sure about what you're saying, don't say it ;) Incorrectly moving it from the answer section into the comment section (which is actually for requesting clarification) doesn't solve the problem of giving potentially false information... Besides, if you'd posted it as an answer, and it turned out to be wrong, then we would have been able to downvote it for you...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work says that requesting clarification is just one use case for comments. *"Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not actually answer their parent questions. Comments are often used to ask for clarification (...)"*

Comment: @ChristianHackl: That doesn't include using comments for posting knowingly potentially incorrect answers :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "knowingly incorrect" sounds too harsh. More like "incomplete" and "not subject to the same self-imposed quality assurance as answers".

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I didn't say "knowingly incorrect". Yes, that would be too harsh, but I didn't say it. I said "knowingly potentially incorrect", which matches what you said about not being sure whether you were correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people write `::std::cout` in order to be *absolutely* sure that they're getting the `cout` from the standard library, since the leading `::` roots the type at the global namespace.

Otherwise it's conceivable that lookup could find some `::haha::trolling::std::cout` name. However, I'd say that this is unlikely.

I do sometimes write `::std` in short function templates that are designed to be highly reusable, just for maximum portability, but it's fairly uncommon. I've seen one SO contributor who stuck to it religiously, but that's about it.

Comment: I vaguely remember that Stefan Ram in comp.lang.c++ used that style.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I can't remember who it was here :(